# Editing on Ipad: Zoom Pages into Margins

Tags: pdf

I have begun to edit my pdflatex documents on an iPad.  In many cases, I finger-pinch the document to expand the font size at the cost of removing the margin.  I am wondering---is there a style or processor that can do this automatically?  That is, a style file to (temporarily) remove the margins and magnify the document on each and every page?

Comment: To change the page layout and margins, [`geometry`](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package is your friend. A quick (yet not so nice) answer: `\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}`.

Comment: really want pdf scaling instead...I want bigger fonts and figures with it...

Comment: So you are requiring a function of LaTeX editor on iPad? For example, you want the output PDF is auto-scaled to show text area without margin when previewed in the editor on iPad?

Comment: not that sophisticated.  really, all I want to do is to post-process the pdf output of pdflatex so that the output is zoomed to remove most of the margins (leaving say, minus 1em).